# How to specify build variables from a particular artifact?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to use [Predefined Build Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in my `Release Pipeline` with CI Trigger enabled. My release pipeline has multiple Artifacts coming in from Multiple separate `Build Pipelines`.

When I use the variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)`, it targets the variable to a specific artifact all the time. I would really like it to use the one from the Build Pipeline that is triggering the deployment. But if that is not possible, can I at least specify which Artifact-set it should use the Build variables from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably do this with a combination of information.  You would first need to get the trigger artifact alias using a [pre-defined release variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release): `Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias`

Then you want to pull details about a specific artifacts build number, you can reference it using a [pre-defined release variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---general-artifact) (replacing with the alias from the first variable):  `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildNumber`

> The build number or the commit identifier.
>
> - Azure Pipelines example: 20170112.1
> - Jenkins/TeamCity example: 20170112.1
> - TFVC example: Changeset 3 Git example: 38629c964
> - GitHub example: 38629c964